# shell one-liner to cat a file only if its ASCII format file

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell, cat

Is it possible to write a one-liner to `cat` a file only if it is a text file, and not if it is a binary?

Something like:

```
echo "/root/mydir/foo" | <if file is ASCII then cat "/root/mydir/foo"; else echo "file is a binary">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the output of the `file` command with the `--mime` and `-b` option.

```
$ file -b --mime filename.bin 
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

The `-b` option suppresses the filename from being printed in the output so you don't have to worry about false matching the filename and `--mime` will give you the character set.

You can use `grep` to test for the occurrence of `charset=binary`

```
$ file -b --mime filename.bin | grep -q "charset=binary"
```

You can then use the exit status of `grep` and the `&&`, `||` operators to `cat` the file or `echo` a message.

```
$ echo filename | xargs -I% bash -c 'file -b --mime % | grep -q "charset=binary" || cat % && echo "binary file"'
```

Finally `xargs` is used to plug in the filename from the previous command `echo filename` and replace the symbol `%` in our binary testing command.

Answer (score 2):

```
filename=$(echo "/root/mydir/foo")
if file "$filename" | grep -q "ASCII text"; then cat "$filename"; else echo "file is a binary"; fi
```

But why does it have to be on one line? It's much more readable if you spread it out:

```
filename=$(echo "/root/mydir/foo")
if file "$filename" | grep -q "ASCII text"
then cat "$filename"
else echo "file is a binary"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Barmer, but the filename comes from a different command, so I showed it as `echo filename` in my question.

Comment: I've replaced it with a variable

Comment: This will also cat binary files like "MPEG v4 system, advanced scalable texture @ L1" and "BLCR context data (little endian, version 2)"

Comment: I've changed it to search for `ASCII text`. Although then it won't match things like `Bourne-Again shell script text executable`. The regexp can be improved to match whatever is desired, the main point of the question seems to be how to incorporate the `grep` command into the script.

Comment: If you use the `-w` option to `grep` it will only list matches that form whole words.  So it will match `script text executable`, but not `advanced scalable texture`

Answer (score 0):

With `$filename` being your file,

```
grep -P '[\x80-\xFF]' "$filename" && echo "file is a binary" || cat "$filename"
```

will be tantamount to `cat` if and only if `$filename` does not contain any non-ASCII character.

Note that GNU `grep` is required, since the one-liner requires Perl-style pattern matching capabilities (`-P`).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what the op is asking, but [strings](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strings.1.html) is dead simple:

```
> strings --help
Usage: strings [option(s)] [file(s)]
Display printable strings in [file(s)] (stdin by default)

strings /root/mydir/foo
```